# JS Autobuild table with dictionary array from category list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work with table, using jquery, for myself i have task t show dictionary data at this table.

For example i have such array:

```
var mokData = [
{ category: "Material", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
{ category: "Material", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of line' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of line' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
{ category: "Tool", id: 'Code0-1', name: 'Brakedown of line' }
];
```

From this array i sort ant get data at my table, but i need build table depends of data which i will receive from server.

```
function pushDataToTable(data, value) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        if (val.category === value) {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + (key + 1) + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td><button class="chose" data-key="' + (key + 1) + '">Chose</button></td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
           } else {
            console.error("Error");
        }

    });

    $('button.chose').on('click', function () {
        var cRow = $(this).parents('tr');
        var cId = $('td:nth-child(2)', cRow).text();
        var intKey = $(this).data('key');

        cRow.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            doChose(cId, intKey);
        });
    });

    function doChose(param1, param2) {
        alert('Data with\n\nID: [' + param1 + ']\nKey: [' + param2 + ']');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".categoryLink").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        var href = $("a", this).attr('href');
        getValueFromHref(href)
    });
});

function getValueFromHref(value) {
    var test = value.replace("#", "")
    pushDataToTable(mokData, test);
}
```

How u can see my JS code, from which i parse data to table, but i have problem.

I have category navigation at my page.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

$('.category_item').click(function () {
    var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');
    console.log(catProduct);

    $('.category_item').removeClass('ct_item-active');
    $(this).addClass('ct_item-active');

    $('.product-item').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
    function hideProduct() {
        $('.product-item').hide();
    } setTimeout(hideProduct, 400);

    function showProduct() {
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').show();
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    } setTimeout(showProduct, 400);
});
});
```

And from this category depends of button click i change data at my table.

Data are sorted. **But previus values are not clear from table**.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <h1>Down time registration</h1>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="store-wrapper">
                <div class="category_list" id="test">
                    <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Technical">Technical</a>
                    <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Organizational">Organizational</a>
                    <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Operator">Operator</a>
                    <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Other">Other</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container2">
                    <div class="section2">
                        <div class="scrollable-content content">
                            <section class="products-list">
                                <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                                    <img src="~/images/udtIcon/equ.png" alt="">
                                    <div class="categoryLink"><a href="#Equipment">Equipment</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                                    <img src="~/images/udtIcon/tool.png" alt="">
                                    <div class="categoryLink"><a href="#Tool">Tool</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                                    <img src="~/images/udtIcon/tool.png" alt="">
                                    <div class="categoryLink"><a href="#Tool">Tool</a></div>
                                </div>

                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-8" id="listItems">
            <div id="scrolltable">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And CSS:

```
wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
}

    .wrap > h1 {
        color: #494B4D;
        font-weight: 400;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 15px 0px;
    }

        .wrap > h1:after {
            content: '';
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            background: #C7C7C7;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

.store-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.category_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
}

    .category_list .category_item {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background: #E84C3D;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .category_list .ct_item-active {
        background: #2D3E50;
    }

.products-list {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


    .products-list .product-item {
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        align-self: flex-start;
        transition: all .4s;
        display: none;
    }

        .products-list .product-item img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .products-list .product-item a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px 0;
            background: #2D3E50;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
.container2 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
}

.section2 {

    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* for Firefox */
    min-height: 0;
}

.content {
    padding: 2px;
}

.scrollable-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

So conclution is, i have problem with dictionary array which are not clear after chosing new category from category list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typos in your code.
I have created a fiddle with the code you have posted above, cleaned it up and made a couple of small changes and it appears to work as you require.

- I cleaned up some html (missing div tags added)
  Changed the line :

  ```
  <tbody></tbody>
  ```

to this

```
<tbody id="tableResults"></tbody>
```

- At the start of the function I added this:

`$("#tableResults").html('');`

which clears the table before it is rebuilt.

Then added

```
$("#tableResults").append(tr);
//$('tbody').append(tr);
```

which builds up your new table

[View the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/jwqd2mo0/9/)